# Incorrect loop and out of bound for HashMap when try to count same value twice

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

This code below takes user input(int values) and then finds duplicate, even number, number count.

*2 problems*:

> 1. The 1st even number gets printed 3 times, if in your input you have
>      2    7     19 8 it will look like 2, 2, 2, 8  . Why I am unable to
>      understand.
> 2. The hashmap part where I put `list.get(intNum)+1` to count a value
>      twice gives out of bound. Without that it runs. How can I count a
>      number twice?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Various {

    static Scanner userinput= new Scanner(System.in);
    static int nums;
    static int big;//will be used to find bug number in array
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();//for all numbers
        List<Integer> listEven= new ArrayList<>(); //just for evens
        Map<Integer,Integer> hmap= new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); //number count

        System.out.println("Enter some numbers: ");
        nums=userinput.nextInt();
        big=nums;
        int evenNumber;

        list.add(nums);

        while(userinput.hasNextInt()){
            nums=userinput.nextInt();

            //below part of the code finds biggest value
            if(nums>big){
                big=nums;
            }
            //Above part of the code finds biggest value

            list.add(nums);

            //below part of the code finds/prints duplicate value
            for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++){           
                for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
                    if(list.get(i)==list.get(j)){
                        System.out.println("Duplicate " + list.get(j));
                    }
                }
                //Above part of the code finds/prints duplicate value
            }
            //below part of the code finds even numbers
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                //for loop will start from 0 till user input            
                if(list.get(i)%2==0){
                    //if any of those i values%2=0 those will be Even and I will capture those
                    listEven.add(list.get(i));
                }
                //Above part of the code finds even numbers
            }
            //below part of the code finds number occurrence count          
            for(Integer intNum: list){
                if(!(hmap).containsKey(intNum)){
                    hmap.put(intNum, 1);
                }else{
                    //below part to take care if a number comes twice i add 1 more(+1)
                    hmap.put(intNum, list.get(intNum)+1);
                }   
                //Above part of the code finds number occurrence count  
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Values are " + list);
        System.out.println("Biggest value " + big);
        System.out.println("Even numbers " + listEven);
        System.out.println("Numbers in list and occurance " + hmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue A:

In your code you have a `while` loop which checks for numbers, but everytime the user enters a number you loop through the list of numbers and check for even numbers.

The most logical way would be to change your code so it checks for even numbers after the user has entered all of their numbers. Or you can add this, which is a lesser solution but it'll work:

---

```
listEven.add(list.get(i));
```

Change the code above to the code below.

```
if (!listEven.contains(list.get(i))) {
    listEven.add(list.get(i));
}
```

### Issue B:

The error lies in this code:

```
// below part of the code finds number occurrence count
for (Integer intNum : list) {
    if (!(hmap).containsKey(intNum)) {
        hmap.put(intNum, 1);
    } else {
        // below part to take care if a number comes twice i add 1
        // more(+1)
        hmap.put(intNum, list.get(intNum) + 1);
    }
    // Above part of the code finds number occurrence count
}
```

---

You're trying to do `list.get(intNum)` however the method `get` requires an **index**, and *not* the value you're trying to find. I think you meant to type `hmap.get(intNum)` instead of `list.get(intNum)`, this will update the count correctly.